# Loading multiple bitmaps

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple android game. This is the first time I am making one, and I am trying to load all the sprites and scenes as bitmaps. I have created a separate loader class for loading several bitmaps, which I will later make a Runnable, but for now, the problem is that even though I have scaled down the bitmaps to the lowest quality possible, I still get an out of memory error. What am I doing wrong? And how do other games implement graphics? Here is the code of the load function:

```
public Map<Elements, Bitmap> load(ArrayList<BitmapData> level) {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Map<Elements, Bitmap> loadedBitmaps = new HashMap<>();
    ByteArrayOutputStream compressed = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] compressedData;
    for(BitmapData data : level){
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), data.id, options);
        options.inSampleSize = Background.calculateInSampleSize(options, data.size.x, data.size.y);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), data.id, options);
        //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, compressed);
        //compressedData = compressed.toByteArray();
        //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(compressedData, 0, compressedData.length); 
        //will the above commented block improve performance??
        loadedBitmaps.put(data.element, bitmap);
    }
    return loadedBitmaps;
}
```

Here is the bitmap data class:

```
public class BitmapData {
    int id;
    Elements element;
    Point size;

    BitmapData(int id, Elements element, Point size){
        this.id = id;
        this.element = element;
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

I would gladly provide more if it's needed, the images that I am loading are of around 200-250 kbs and range from about 4-8 in number, depending on the scene.

On a side note, the profiler shows 80 mb allocated to graphics and 50mb allocated to java, why are these values so high? Is it normal for java allocated memory to reach 50mb?

PS: I tried looking for other solutions but I couldn't find any, also if possible  I'd like to do this by myself at least once to get a better understanding of how the other libraries like picasso or glide work.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution would be using the Glide library.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Add this to gradle:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
}
```

This is much more memory-friendly and will take care of everything for you. The commands are discribed on github, but it will be something as simple as:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageSource)
    .into(myImageView);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help man :)
But I'd like to try it once without libraries too, though I will use glide later on to make sure nothing goes wrong 